# lot size formula for cfd and forex based on risk percentage

Tags: risk, risk-management, money-management

I have a question regarding the calculation of the lot size for cfd and forex instruments when we have a risk amount as a percentage of the balance.

So how to compute the lot size to trade knowing the stop loss value and the entry point value for a buy trade in order to match the risk amount when the stop loss is reached?

Thanks in advance for your answer!

Comment: For example: I have 100,000 USD, I want to buy EUR at 1.10 EURUSD, I want to lose no more that 10% if EURUSD should fall to 1.05. How much EUR should I buy. Is this an example of what you are asking?

Comment: yes this is my qestion!